# Class active no menu utilizando include

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-3

Em minhas páginas php utilizo um include para chamar um arquivo que contém meu menu:

```
<?php include('../../sidebar-menu.php'); ?>
```

Arquivo com menu:

```
   <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
             <?php 
                foreach ($lista as $key => $value) {
                  echo '<li class="mt">
                      <a href="/view/DadosIndicadores/index.php?id_tipo='.$lista[$key]['id'].'">
                          <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                          <span>'.$lista[$key]['nome'].'</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>';
                }
              ?>
    </ul>
```

Como faço para inserir a class active apenas no menu acessado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O PHP tem uma constante mágica que te retorna qual é o arquivo que está rodando. Essa constante é a [__FILE__](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php).

Digamos que você tenha os arquivos:
index.php = Página Principal
sobre.php = Sobre a empresa
contato.php = Fale conosco

Ali dentro do seu foreach, você faria uns if's tipo assim:

```
<?php
  foreach ($lista as $key => $value) {
      $ativo = '';

      if($lista[$key]['nome'] === 'Página Principal' && __FILE__ === 'index.php') {
         $ativo = ' active';
      } elseif($lista[$key]['nome'] === 'Sobre a empresa' && __FILE__ === 'sobre.php') {
         $ativo = ' active';
      } elseif($lista[$key]['nome'] === 'Fale conosco' && __FILE__ === 'contato.php') {
         $ativo = ' active';
      }

      echo '<li class="mt'.$ativo.'">
              <a href="/view/DadosIndicadores/index.php?id_tipo='.$lista[$key]['id'].'">
                  <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                  <span>'.$lista[$key]['nome'].'</span>
              </a>
            </li>';
  }
?>
```

Essa é apenas uma sugestão de código. Tem várias maneiras de escrever isso... Eu dei uma sugestão bem simples e não muito elegante, apenas para você entender a ideia do que você precisa.

Deixo sob sua responsabilidade melhorar a escrita! ^^

Comment: Aqui a utilização do __FILE__ não trouxe o nome do arquivo da página, mas sim trouxe o nome do arquivo do menu sidebar-menu.php. Não é bem este nome que deveria aparecer, correto?

Comment: Esqueci que você estava fazendo include! Tenta criar uma variável no cabeçalho do arquivo da página acessada, que guarda o que está na constante \__FILE__, antes de você chamar o include, e aí veja se o include consegue ler essa variável... Se der certo, aí é só trocar o \__FILE__ dos if's.

De qualquer forma, por que você não estuda usar o [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org) como sistema de template?